# Passing data to Parent but lagging

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a [Semantic-ui-react dropdown](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown) component with states. As it is, each dropdown clicked option updates state accordingly (clicking on 'Biomasa' logs 1, then clicking on 'Eólica' logs 2, and so on). **Ok.**

Then, I want to *pass* that data to a Parent. I decided to do it by *wrapping* the dropdown component inside another one. Luckily, I will be able to render different Google Maps Markers (given the selected dropdown option).

**Problem is**: the passed data is lagged (as you can see in the log), why is that? Sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/303z036xx6).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Marker } from "react-gmaps";

const sen_data3 = [
  {
    text: "Biomasa",
    value: 1,
    key: "biomasa"
  },
  {
    text: "Eólica",
    value: 2,
    key: "eolica"
  },
  {
    text: "Geotérmica",
    value: 3,
    key: "geotermica"
  },
  {
    text: " Hidroeléctrica",
    value: 4,
    key: "hidroelectrica"
  },
  {
    text: "Residuo Sólido",
    value: 5,
    key: "residuo"
  },
  {
    text: "Solar",
    value: 6,
    key: "solar"
  },
  {
    text: "Térmica",
    value: 7,
    key: "térmica"
  }
];

class TheMapDropdown32Markers extends React.Component {
  receiveChild = valueData => {
    console.log("valueData passed to Parent", valueData);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("valueData passed to parent", this.receiveChild());
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Hey, filter</div>
        <TheMapDropdown32 onChange2={this.receiveChild} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TheMapDropdown32 extends React.Component {
  state = {
    valueData: undefined
  };

  handleChange = (evt, { value }) => {
    this.setState({ valueData: value });
    this.props.onChange2(this.state.valueData);
  };

  render() {
    console.log("this.state.valueData Child", this.state.valueData);
    return (
      <Dropdown
        placeholder={"Seleccione Categoría"}
        options={sen_data3}
        selection
        value={this.state.valueData}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TheMapDropdown32Markers />, document.getElementById("gmaps"));
```

Comment: check `handleChange` method in `TheMapDropdown32` and check the duplicate question, you should be able to figure out the issue

Comment: Wow, it worked. TBH, I also tried setting the console log in the callback as a 2nd parameter inside the SetState method, but it didn't worked. Only after I did as you said (as a *function*), it did worked. May I know why?

Comment: Because setState callback takes the second argument as a function and not a expression

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: Hi again, so I ran into a new question. The data is pased ok (from the dropdown component to another one). But the only way I could do it was to create another state in the new component. So, is that valida? I mean it works, but so I have a dropdown comp with state, passing data to another comp with its own state, you know to have dinamic data as well. I guess this is because since I am using a semantic ui react component and the way it is already created. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are the two of your dropdowns siblings of one other

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163727/discussion-between-mauricio-maroto-and-shubham-khatri).